# ReportBuilder and ReportViewer changes date in parameters box after running the report

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, date-format, reportbuilder

On the Server I have set the **Region and Language Format** to **English (United States)** and changed **Short date** format to "**dd-MMM-yy**".

After that created report which is accepting start date and end date as parameter in calendar control

While running report from ReportBuilder or ReportViewer which accepting date in "dd-MMM-yy", so entered start date "**5-Aug-13**" and end date "**10-Aug-13**" then clicked on View Report button its fetching correct data between that date range but parameters values get changed to start date "**8-May-13**" and end date "**8-Oct-13**".

Why this is happening?

I am Using Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2